# Check Specific Connections within Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Say you have the skeleton of a graph:

```
nodeset= PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "SkeletonRules"]
```

and you've an arbitrary list of some fraction of those nodes, say `given = {1,4,10}`, which you want to turn into the list of all nodes ***connected*** directly to those `given`  (along with the number of `given` each is connected to).

With,

```
connCheckTool[node1_, node2_] := Count[nodeset, (node1 -> node2)] + Count[nodeset,(node2 -> node1)]
```

The following function achieves this:

```
DeleteCases[
   DeleteCases[
    Transpose@{Range[20], 
       Total /@ 
    Table[connCheckTool[i, given[[z]]], {i, 1, 120, 1}, {z, 
      1, Length@given}]} /. {x_Integer, 0} -> delete, delete], {x_, y_} /; 
MemberQ[given, x] == True];
```

However, the inner `connCheckTool` is not very efficient, especially with larger graphs.

Can anyone think of a way to accomplish this in a better way?

I suspect it will involve the `AdjacencyMatrix` of the original, whole graph, as opposed to the list-search mechanism, but can't quite get it...

Comment: Checked [AdjacencyList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NeighborhoodGraph.html) in the docs? And [NeighborhoodGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NeighborhoodGraph.html) and [SubGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subgraph.html)?

Comment: I had an apparently undue paranoia of using `Graph` objects more than needed.  Thank you for correcting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tally[Join @@ (AdjacencyList[Graph[nodeset], #] & /@ given)]
```

> {{1, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}, {17, 1},
>       {20,  1}, {41, 1}, {52, 1}, {71, 1}, {76, 1}, {105, 1},{109, 1}, {113, 1}}